# Concept of integration over the probability density function (pdf) $f\left( {r,\theta } \right)$.

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Suppose I have a joint probability density function (pdf)  $f\left( {r,\theta } \right)$ where, $r \in \left[ {0,\infty } \right];\theta  \in \left[ {0,2\pi } \right], z\in re^{j\theta}$.

Let the pdf $f\left( {r,\theta } \right)$ is continuous and differentiable at every point over the interval mentioned above. I am trying to come up with the following relation,

$\int\limits_0^\infty  {\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {{e^{r\cos (\theta  - \phi )}}} f\left( {r,\theta } \right)d\theta dr}  \approx \int\limits_0^\infty  {g(r)f\left( r \right)dr} $

where, $f(r)$ is the marginal pdf.

1. Is there any way I can use the concept of integration over the CDF or pdf (I heard about Riemann-Stieltjes integral, Lebesgue integral, etc. I am not sure if I can use this concept under some condition. )
2. Is there any advice or example or theorem that can help me solve the problem.